# Hide/Show Image

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to hide/show an image when you click on a button. I wish to only use JavaScript, CSS, and HTML in this small project. The code I have so far is:

```
<span id = "one">
<img src = "1.png" alt = "Picture of 1" style="display: none;"/>
</span>

<input type="button" value="One" onclick="showOne();" />

<script type = "text/javascript" src= "123clickJs.js">
</script>
```

^ That is the HTML.

Here is the JavaScript:

```
function showOne() {
var img1 = document.getElementById("one");
img1.style.display = "";
  if(img1.style.display == "inline" ) {
    img1.style.display = "none";
  }
  else {
  img1.style.display = "inline";
  }
}
```

But for some reason, it is not toggling the image visible/hidden. Any ideas on what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: You should seriously look into JQuery if you haven't already. This show/hide can be done with a simple .toggle() function.

Comment: You are changing the style for span but your image will always be hidden because it has its own inline-style

Comment: @Overflow Don't be ridiculous. There's no need to load a library for something like this.

Comment: @Nit right....but he should still look into JQuery.

Comment: Rather - target image: http://jsfiddle.net/vu1huv0k/

Comment: @DhirajBodicherla, thank you. What do you suggest I do to fix it?

Comment: @Overflow Not really. jQuery, unlike some people like to think, is not the end-all-be-all library of Javascript. Rather often you don't even need a library to begin with, the above question is a good example of which.

Comment: give the image an `id` and reference that first in your `showOne` function

Comment: @Nit fair enough :) I stand corrected.

Answer (score 3):

Hiding or showing anything is more straightforward if you use a class to control the styles.

```js
document.getElementById('button').onclick = function () {
  document.getElementById('target').classList.toggle('show');
}
```

```css
#target {
  display: none;
}
#target.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<input id="button" type="button" value="Toggle the image" />

<img id="target" src="http://i.imgur.com/a2F7iyp.jpg" alt="Picture of 1" />
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you first set `img1.style.display = ""` and then check if it is `inline` or `none`. It will always be `""` here so the `if` condition is always ignored.

Try this instead:

```
function showOne() {
  var img1 = document.getElementById("one");
  if (!img1.style.display !== "none") {
    // If the image is displayed, whatever its style is, hide it
    img1.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    // Otherwise display it
    img1.style.display = "inline";
  }
}
```

Comment: To the one who downvoted my answer, please explain what you think is wrong with it.

Answer (score -1):

I think you can just simply use toggle()

JavaScript

```
$("#radio_btn").on("click", function () {
    $('.img_display').toggle();
});
```

HTML

```
<span id="one">
<img class="img_display" src = "http://www.monochrome-photo.info/home/nbigeast/monochrome-photo.info/public_html/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/1349454271_apple.png" alt = "Picture of 1" style="display: none;">
</span>

<input type="button" value="One" id="radio_btn" />
```